# how to save docx file that is loaded in webBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, save

I have loaded (navigated) a word document (.docx) in a webBrowser control (MS Word is installed). A user may change the content of the file. The question is: is that possible to save the changed document programmatically in C#?

Regards

Comment: The answer is: yes, it is possible.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could provide the answer. thanks.